# Flash effect using front facing camera Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, flash, swift, camera

So I have searched for hours on a solution to this and have attempted using filters with no success. I was wondering how can I create a flash effect using the front face camera but then modify the image so it looks like it added the flash as if it was using the back camera? I know a few apps such as snapchat have done this but I could not find a tutorial on how to achieve it. I have tried adjusting brightness, gamma & exposure with no success.

NOTE: I know there is no flash on a front camera for iOS.

EDIT: I am thinking it is possible by setting the screen brightness to the max, animating then going back to the previous brightness.

Answer (score 1):

On an iOS device you take a screenshot when you press home + lock and the screen flashes white. Do you mean this effect? If so, try this:

Add a UIView with a white background color to your view hierarchy such that it covers the whole screen. Then, start an animation that fades the opacity of this view to zero. On completion, remove the view from its superview:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 
             animations: ^{
                           whiteView.alpha = 0.0;
                         }
             completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                           [whiteView removeFromSuperview];
                         }
];
```

If you want the entire screen to flash, add the white view to the application's UIWindow and set the frame accordingly. All buttons work all the time, if you add the white view just in the moment before the animation starts and remove it on completion - except during the short flash

Comment: Yes, this is part of it, but I want the actual image to be brighter, it is still dark.

Comment: what you are talking is about creating a photo filter,in your case you would have to apply it immediately after the photo is taken.it wont be easy but you can refer to this link.[Creating filters for ios](http://taptaptap.com/blog/creating-a-camera-plus-fx/)

Comment: Not a problem, I am willing to figure it out, just could not find a good solution on the internet. I have tried using CIFilters with no luck. I will check out the link and get back to you.

Comment: I have checked it out a little bit, but not really sure how this points to improving the brightness of the image. I understand you can do effects to an image (I assume changing brightness is part of that) but I am unsure if this will lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work by increasing the system brightness right before the photo was taken, then resetting the value back. This would allow such brightness to reflect against someones face when in a dark room. If anyone wants to see the code, let me know. It is in Swift.